# I want to use ?. in a React project but it throws an error

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing a problem with React. If I use `?.` it throws an error

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (21:22)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   var navigate = useNavigate();
|   var location = useLocation();
>   var from = location?.state?.from?.pathname || "/";      
|   var userRef = React.useRef();
|   var errRef = React.useRef();
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to either upgrade to webpack 5 or use `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining`

Reference: [Webpack issues](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10227)

Answer (score 0):

The Optional Chaining `?.` operator wasn't added to Node until version 14. Make sure you have the right version installed. You can check which version of node you are using with `node -v`

You could also use a transcompiler like Babel which will implement unsupported features to make your code 'backwards compatible'

See: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-optional-chaining.html